# RQuantLib fails to load

Tags: r, macos

I've recently updated all packages. Now RQuantLib fails to load. What can I do? I've tried to remove and reinstall the package in version 0.3.12 both from CRAN and from the source file, neither helps.

```
> library(RQuantLib)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RQuantLib', details:
call: if (is.character(qc) && nchar(qc) > 1) {
error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'bash -c 'type -p quantlib-config' 2>/dev/null' had status 1 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RQuantLib’
```

I'm working in RStudio with R 3.0.2 on Mac OS Mavericks. What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried using the standard R GUI? Is this an RStudio-only error?

Comment: Try updating to the latest R 3.1.0 version and see if that helps.

Comment: I have the same problem. On RQuantLib webpage, http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RQuantLib/index.html, it shows OS X Mavericks binaries: r-release: not available.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after some hours of struggle I manage to use something not very rigorous but it works!
It seems that R has some issues evaluating `system("bash -c 'type -p quantlib-config'")`.
After having installed QuantLib, typing the command `bash -c 'type -p quantlib-config'` in Terminal gives us the path of our quantlib-config which is for me `/opt/local/bin/quantlib-config`.

So I went back to my **source** folder for RQuantLib (version 0.4.0) and replaced qc in file `R/inline.R`by:

> `qc <- as.character("/opt/local/bin/quantlib-config")`

and rebuilt the package using the terminal command `R CMD install RQuantLib/`.
As I said, not very sexy but it works.
A restart of R and Rstudio is necessary.

Hope it helps the next ones and that this will be corrected in future versions.