# require(RQuantLib) fails

Tags: r, quantlib

I am trying to load RQuantLib but I get the following error:

```
> require(RQuantLib)
Loading required package: RQuantLib
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RQuantLib', details:
  call: if (is.character(qc) && nchar(qc) > 1) {
  error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'bash -c 'type -p quantlib-config' 2>/dev/null' had status 1
```

I am pretty new to programming in general so I am not sure what this means. I am working in an Mac OS Maverick environment, I downloaded the latest version of RQuantLib (0.3.12) and the "R Package Installer" says it is installed. (I installed RQuantLib from the terminal using "R CMD INSTALL RQuantLib" as using install.packages() from within R did not work - it gave me an error saying QuantLib was not configured, although it was running fine in from the terminal.) I am running R from the R console. QuantLib works fine and so does Rcpp.

I checked the "NAMESPACE" document in the RQuantLib folder and it says:

```
import(methods)
importFrom(Rcpp, Rcpp.plugin.maker)

useDynLib(RQuantLib)

exportPattern("*.default")

export(
       ##--arrays.R
       "oldEuropeanOptionArrays",
       "EuropeanOptionArrays",
       "plotOptionSurface",
       ##--asian.R
       "AsianOption",
       ##--bermudan.R
       "BermudanSwaption",
       "summary.G2Analytic",
       "summary.HWAnalytic",
       "summary.HWTree",
       "summary.BKTree",
       ##--bond.R
       "ZeroCouponBond",
       "ZeroPriceByYield",
       "ZeroYield",
       "FixedRateBond",
       "FixedRateBondYield",
       "FixedRateBondPriceByYield",
       "FloatingRateBond",
       "ConvertibleZeroCouponBond",
       "ConvertibleFixedCouponBond",
       "ConvertibleFloatingCouponBond",
       "CallableBond",
       "FittedBondCurve",
       ##--calendars.R
       "isBusinessDay", "businessDay",
       "isHoliday",
       "isWeekend",
       "isEndOfMonth",
       "getEndOfMonth", "endOfMonth",
       "adjust",
       "advance",
       "businessDaysBetween",
       "getHolidayList", "holidayList",
       "setCalendarContext",
       ##--dayCounter.R
       "dayCount",
       "yearFraction",
       "setEvaluationDate",
       ##--discount.R
       "DiscountCurve",
       "plot.DiscountCurve",
       ##--implied.R
       "EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility",
       "AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility",
       "BinaryOptionImpliedVolatility",
       ##--option.R
       "EuropeanOption",
       "AmericanOption",
       "AmericanOption.default",
       "BinaryOption",
       "BarrierOption"
       )

S3method("plot", "Option")
S3method("print", "Option")
S3method("summary", "Option")

S3method("plot", "Bond")
S3method("print", "Bond")
S3method("summary", "Bond")
```

If I try to specify the path where the Terminal wrote that it installed RQuantLib while requiring it I get the following error:

```
> require('RQuantLib', lib.loc = "C:/Users/dealmer/Library/R/3.1/library/RQuantLib/libs")
Loading required package: RQuantLib
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  no library trees found in 'lib.loc'
```

So, do I need to move something from there to where the other R libraries are? (There is already a folder named "RQuantLib" in the folder where the other R library folders are, that's where I found the NAMESPACE doc for example) The path that the Terminal gave me I can't follow in the Finder window however because it doesn't show the "Library" folder and I don't know how to make it do that.)

This is what .libPaths() gives me:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Users/dealmer/Library/R/3.1/library"                          
[2] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library"
```

The R libraries are in [2].

I've tried googling but I can't find anything that seems helpful. Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you
- Dom

Comment: possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765872/rquantlib-fails-to-load

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that on Linux we have `quantlib-config` in the `$PATH`:

```
edd@max:~$ quantlib-config --help
Usage: quantlib-config [--prefix[=DIR]] [--exec-prefix[=DIR]] [--version] \
                       [--libs] [--cflags]
edd@max:~$ quantlib-config --version
1.4
edd@max:~$
```

I don't own an OS X box, so I depend on someone like *you* help with a better configure setup. It should just work if you copy (or soft-link) `quantlib-config` into your path (eg `/usr/local/bin`), or adjust `$PATH` otherwise to include the directory it is in.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after some hours of struggle I manage to use something not very rigorous but it works!
It seems that R has some issues evaluating `system("bash -c 'type -p quantlib-config'")`.
After having installed QuantLib, typing the command `bash -c 'type -p quantlib-config'` in Terminal gives us the path of our quantlib-config which is for me `/opt/local/bin/quantlib-config`.

So I went back to my **source** folder for RQuantLib (version 0.4.0) and replaced qc in file `R/inline.R`by:

> `qc <- as.character("/opt/local/bin/quantlib-config")`

and rebuilt the package using the terminal command `R CMD install RQuantLib/`.
As I said, not very sexy but it works.
A restart of R and Rstudio is necessary.

Hope it helps!

Comment: As @dirk-eddelbuettel mentioned, you could check if `/opt/local/bin` is on your environment variables. (Run `system("printenv")` from R). If it is not then you'd need to add it.